# How to avoid rounding off values in as.numeric in R?

Tags: r

```
list1 = as.numeric("133601182.5")
133601183
```

It is rounding off the values

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
list1 = as.numeric(133601182.5)
sprintf("%f",list1)
```

OR to get output to `.1` extent only try:

```
list1 = as.numeric(133601182.5)
sprintf("%.01f",list1)
```