# How to avoid number rounding when using as.numeric() in R?

Tags: r, character, number-formatting

I am reading well structured, textual data in R and in the process of converting from character to numeric, numbers lose their decimal places.

I have tried using `round(digits = 2)` but it didn't work since I first had to apply `as.numeric`. At one point, I did set up `options(digits = 2)` before the conversion but it didn't work either.

Ultimately, I desired to get a `data.frame` with its numbers being exactly the same as the ones seen as characters.

I looked up for help here and did find answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308688/how-to-avoid-rounding-off-values-in-as-numeric-in-r), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53574953/when-i-use-as-numeric-all-my-latitude-and-longitude-become-to-1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764258/avoiding-rounding-in-r); however, none really helped me solve this issue.

> How will I prevent number rounding when converting from character to
>   numeric?

Here's a reproducible piece of code I wrote.

```
library(purrr)
my_char = c("      246.00    222.22    197.98    135.10    101.50     86.45
            72.17     62.11     64.94     76.62    109.33    177.80")

# Break characters between spaces
my_char = strsplit(my_char, "\\s+")

head(my_char, n = 2)
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] ""       "246.00" "222.22" "197.98" "135.10" "101.50" "86.45" 
#>  [8] "72.17"  "62.11"  "64.94"  "76.62"  "109.33" "177.80"

# Convert from characters to numeric.
my_char = map_dfc(my_char, as.numeric)


head(my_char, n = 2)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>      V1
#>   <dbl>
#> 1    NA
#> 2   246

# Delete first value because it's empty
my_char = my_char[-1,1]

head(my_char, n = 2)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>      V1
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  246 
#> 2  222.
```

Comment: `sapply(my_char, as.numeric)`?

Comment: Your numbers aren't being rounded. Look at `sprintf("%0.17f", my_char[[1]])` after running your posted code

Comment: are you sure it is not the print method that is limiting the number of decimal places?

Comment: Try `print.data.frame(na.omit(map_dfc(strsplit(my_char, "\\s+"), as.numeric)), digits = 4)`

Comment: Converting to genuine R data frame reveals there is no rounding, try `as.data.frame(my_char)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### It's how R visualize data in a tibble.

The function `map_dfc` is not rounding your data, it's just a way **R** use to display data in a `tibble`.

If you want to print the data with the usual format, use `as.data.frame`, like this:

```
head(as.data.frame(my_char), n = 4)
       V1
#>1  246.00
#>2  222.22
#>3  197.98
#>4  135.10
```

Showing that your data has not been rounded.

Hope this helps.